# --regextrans2: command not found

Tags: bash, command-line

I was testing imapsync 1.727 to sync imap from an older version of zimbra (7.1.4) to version 8.7.7 and got an error as above with command below:

```
imapsync \
  --maxsize 52428800 --buffersize 8192000 \
  --nofoldersizes --nosyncacls --subscribe --syncinternaldates \
  --authmech2 PLAIN \
  --exclude '(?i)\b(Junk|Spam|Trash)\b' \
  --skipheader 'X-*' \
  --regexflag 's/\\\\(Answered|Flagged|Deleted|Seen|Recent|Draft)[^\s]*\s*//ig' --debugflags \
  --regextrans2 's,:,-,g' \
  --regextrans2 's,\",'\'',g' \
  --regextrans2 's,\s+(?=/|$),,g' \
  --regextrans2 's,^(Briefcase|Calendar|Contacts|Emailed Contacts|Notebook|Tasks)(?=/|$), $1 Folder,ig' \
  --host1 "$host1" --host2 "$host2" \
  --user1 "$username" --authuser1 admin_account_name \
  --password1 admin_account_password \
  --user2 "$username" --authuser2 admin_account_name \
  --password2 admin_account_password \
  --regextrans2 's,\",-,g' \ # change quotes to dashes
  --regextrans2 's,&AAo-|&AA0ACg-|&AA0ACgANAAo-(?=/|$),,g' \
  --ssl1 --authmech1 PLAIN --maxcommandlength1 16384 \
  --dry --debug --debugimap \
```

Why it failed on line 18 but not regtrans2 on other lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a line continuation that is followed by a comment on the same line.

This is ok:

```
echo \
hello
```

This is not ok:

```
echo \ #newline here
hello
```

In the first example, the `\` escapes the newline, and the command that is executed will be `echo hello`.

In the second case, the `\` just escapes the space after it, and we get `#newline here` as output, followed by the error message `hello: not found [No such file or directory]` (or similar).

So, remove the comment (*everything*, including the space, after the last `\`) on the line that now reads

```
--regextrans2 's,\",-,g' \ # change quotes to dashes
```

Answer (score 0):

Remembering from past experiences, it may seems like it have to be re arranged specifically like below, then it works.

```
imapsync \
  --dry \
  --host1 "$host1" --host2 "$host2" \
  --user1 "$username" --authuser1 admin \
  --ssl1 --authmech1 PLAIN \
  --password1 "$admin_account_password" \
  --user2 "$username" --authuser2 admin \
  --ssl2 --authmech2 PLAIN  \
  --password2 "$admin_account_password" \
  --maxsize 52428800 --buffersize 8192000 \
  --nofoldersizes --nosyncacls --subscribe --syncinternaldates \
  --authmech2 PLAIN \
  --exclude '(?i)\b(Junk|Spam|Trash)\b' \
  --skipheader 'X-*' \
  --regextrans2 "s,&AAo-|&AA0ACg-|&AA0ACgANAAo-(?=/|$),,g" \
  --regexflag 's/\\\\(?!Answered|Flagged|Deleted|Seen|Recent|Draft)[^\s]*\s*//ig' --debugflags \
  --regextrans2 's,:,-,g' \
  --regextrans2 's,\",'\'',g' \
  --regextrans2 's,\s+(?=/|$),,g' \
  --regextrans2 "s,^(Briefcase|Calendar|Contacts|Emailed Contacts|Notebook|Tasks)(?=/|$), $1 Folder,ig" \
  --regextrans2 's,\",-,g' \
```